# Cam access for embedded iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have to embed my video chat app into a simple iframe
As you can see it needs cam and mic access.
how do I envoke access for the embedded website in iframe
following is the simple code
`<iframe src="somewebsite" style="width: 100% ;height: 100%;"></iframe>`

Comment: iframes have an [allow attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) where you can specify access to certain [feature policies](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Feature_Policy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the `allow` attribute worked for me:

```
<iframe src="https://example.com" allow="camera; microphone"/>
```

Comment: what about `allow="camera"` for camera only?